# Table is starting in the middle CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a little problem... this is the page I'm working with
http://www.laget.se/storvretensff/Page/179025 but as you can see it starts with blank a few rows then my code starts. I want my info directly after the big text "LEDARE". Can someone help me with this?

```
<html><table width="300" border="1">
<tr> <td><div class="LedarInfo">
        <table style="width: 50" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Namn</th><td>Askin Ünsal</td></tr><tr><th>Position</th><td>Tränare</td></tr>      </table>
    </div> 

<div class='imagediv '><a class='fancybox' rel='single' title=' '  href='http://img.laget.se/2723013.jpg'><img class='profileImgThumb' src='http://img.laget.se/2723013.jpg' width="100" height="150"style='' /></a></div>
        </div></td> 

 <td><div class="LedarInfo">
        <table style="width: 50" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Namn</th><td>Burak Tütüncu </td></tr><tr><th>Position</th><td>Ass.Tränare</td></tr>        </table>
    </div> 
 <div class='imagediv ' ><a class='fancybox' rel='single' title=' ' href='http://img.laget.se/405720/2161962.jpg'><img class='profileImgThumb' src='http://img.laget.se/405720/2161962.jpg' width="100" height="150"style='' /></a></div>
        </div></td>
</tr>
<tr>

    <td><div class="LedarInfo">
        <table style="width: 50" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Namn</th><td>Aydin Ünsal </td></tr><tr><th>Position</th><td>Ass. Tränare </td></tr>       </table>
    </div> 
 <div class='imagediv ' ><a class='fancybox' rel='single' title=' ' href='http://img.laget.se/405720/2161962.jpg'><img class='profileImgThumb' src='http://img.laget.se/405720/2161962.jpg' width="100" height="150"style='' /></a></div>
        </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>` tags below, in the  div `<div class="pageContent">`

Comment: in which row i dont have <br>

Comment: You have it in your main code, not in example above. @Vucko sugested removing them also.